# How to prove triangle inequality for max function?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

> Suppose $d(p_1, p_2)$ = max(|$x_1 - x_2$|, |$y_1 - y_2$|).
>   Prove the triangle inequality for $d(p_1, p_2)$

I've never worked with max($x, y$) functions before. What is the trick to proving this problem? My initial thought was proving it separately for all 8 possible combinations:

$a + b \ge c$, $a + c \ge b$, $a + b \ge a$, .... and so on.

But I feel like there is a much more "elegant" way to do it. Any tips would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Show that for any $a,b,c,d,$ $\max(a,b) + \max (c,d) \ge \max( a+c, b+d)$.

Comment: Another hint: $\max(a,b):=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $(x_i, y_i) \in \mathbb R^2$ for $i = 1,2,3$. Observe that
$$\begin{aligned}
|x_1 - x_3| & \leq |x_1 - x_2| + |x_2 - x_3| \\
& \leq \max(|x_1 - x_2|, |y_1 - y_2|) + \max(|x_2 - x_3|, |y_2 - y_3|)\\
\end{aligned}$$
and similarly,
$$\begin{aligned}
|y_1 - y_3| & \leq |y_1 - y_2| + |y_2 - y_3| \\
& \leq \max(|x_1 - x_2|, |y_1 - y_2|) + \max(|x_2 - x_3|, |y_2 - y_3|)\\
\end{aligned}$$
Note that the RHS is the same in both inequalities. Now use the fact that
$$a \leq c \text{ and } b \leq c \ \iff \ \max(a, b) \leq c$$
to conclude that
$$\max(|x_1 - x_3|, |y_1 - y_3|) \leq \max(|x_1 - x_2|, |y_1 - y_2|) + \max(|x_2 - x_3|, |y_2 - y_3|)$$
which is the triangle inequality.